# Create one slider for every wordpress page with the title's page with revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider, page-title

I would like to create a slider for every page of my website with the title of this page in it. I would like to do this without create a slider for each page, is it possible to do this automatically? To charge the title page automatically in the revolution slider?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

1.) Add a layer to the slider that will contain the title.

2.) Under "Advanced Parameters", give that layer an ID, for example #MyLayerID.

3.) Add a jQuery code that changes the value of the element with that ID with the title of the current page, something like:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        $('#MyLayerID').text(title);
    }
);
```

**Regarding the title - site name question:**

You can try this:

```
title=title.substr(0,title.lastIndexOf("-"));
```